# Error: Computed property was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: vue.js

I used in mapGetters for get param from store,

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters("agent",["getConfig"]),
}
```

It is working well, But it do error:

> [Vue warn]: Computed property "getConfig" was assigned to but it has no setter.

I tried do it with Get and Set:

```
computed: {
getConfig: {
    get: () => this.$state.getters.getConfig,
    set: (value) => this.$state.commit('setConfiguration', value ) }}
```

But I have error:

> vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "getConfig": "TypeError: Cannot read property '$state' of undefined"

What is the correct syntax to make Get and Set for "GetConfig" in computed?

Answer (score 2):

The context of `this` is lost in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

So just change to:

```
 get: function() { 
   return this.$state.getters.getConfig
 },
 set: function(value) {
   this.$state.commit('setConfiguration', value ) 
 }
```